# How can i remove the watches one by one when i fire watch on element for multiple times?

Tags: angularjs

I will fire watch multiple times on input field by clicking on start watch.
And now I want to remove the watches one by one on that are present on the input field. How can I do it?

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('docsBindExample', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Max Karl Ernst Ludwig Planck (April 23, 1858 – October 4, 1947)';

      $scope.test = "";
      $scope.cntr = 0;    /* jsCode igonore other methods*/
      $scope.initWatch = function() {
        $scope.$watch('test', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue !== oldValue)
            $scope.cntr++;
        });
      };

    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-directive-bind-production</title>

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="docsBindExample">  <!--html code-->
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" />

    <input type="button" value="start watch" ng-click="initWatch()" />   <!-- watch is called multiple times by clicking it-->

    <br/> Watch Counter: {{cntr}}   <!-- count displayed here -->

  </div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->     <!-- if version <Named Framework> [gte 2.0] -->
Content relevant to Named Framework versions 2.0 and greater.
<!-- end version if -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a watcher, use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="watch()"/>
<input type="button" value="enable watch" ng-click="enableWatch()" />
```

Instead of adding and removing a watcher, use an `enable` flag:

```
  $scope.enableWatch = function() {
      $scope.enable = ! $scope.enable;
  };
  $scope.watch = function() {
      if ($scope.enable) {
        $scope.cntr++;
      };
  };
```

The technique of adding and removing watchers creates an implicit state that is difficult to see and difficult to debug. That technique should be avoided. Instead adding a flag creates a state that is readily visible and easily debugged. This follows the design principle of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) where the model is separated from the view and its watchers.

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module('docsBindExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Max Karl Ernst Ludwig Planck (April 23, 1858 – October 4, 1947)';

      $scope.test = "";
      $scope.cntr = 0;    /* jsCode igonore other methods*/
      $scope.enableWatch = function() {
          $scope.enable = ! $scope.enable;
      };
      $scope.watch = function() {
          if ($scope.enable) {
            $scope.cntr++;
          };
      };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="docsBindExample">  <!--html code-->
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="watch()"/>

    <input type="button" value="enable watch" ng-click="enableWatch()" />
    
    <br/>
    <p ng-show="enable">Watch enabled</p>
    Watch Counter: {{cntr}}   
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can deregister the `$watch` since it return a deregister function

```
var listener = $scope.initWatch = function() {
    $scope.$watch('test', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue)
            $scope.cntr++;
    });
}; 


listener(); // clear the watch
```

Comment: when i hit start watch for 2 times count increments every time by 2 values but instead of clearing the watch i want to remove the one of the watch so that counter increments by 1 value only

Comment: even through it removed the watch it does not remove the `scope.cntr` value. then you need to manually assign that variable to 1

Comment: yes but i want watch still to be exist on input field, if there are more than 1 watches then counter will count more values.so i want to remove the extra watches untill the counter count only 1 value (instead of completely de registering the watch)

Comment: after the watch add this `$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function ()
        {
            $scope.cntr = 1;
        });`

Comment: this will remove destroy all the watches